# What does 'make a complete pigs here' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

I was watching this video: https://youtu.be/EaJt5jC5gbY?t=1228

Time Stamp: 20:30

Here the author says: ***"The human race made a complete pigs here of that initial management of this virus."***

I think there is no dictionary that has a definition for this phrase. I have already searched the internet to no avail. I have no clue what it could possibly mean. Or, Have I heard it wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The video say "a pig's ear"..

[Collins Dictionary *pig's ear*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pigs-ear)
"something that has been badly or clumsily done;
a botched job
(especially in the phrase **make a pig's ear of** (something)) "

There is an old proverb:
"You can't make a silk purse from a sow's ear.", meaning you can't make a fine product from inferior materials.
[Word Histories *silk purse out of a sow's ear*](https://wordhistories.net/2016/12/28/silk-purse-sows-ear/)

The figure of speech "make a pig's ear of" may make reference to that proverb, though that's just speculation on my part.

Comment: Ahh. Then why did I hear it wrong? Ohh dear! Is there something wrong with my ear?

Comment: There was something wrong with your *here*, but that's fixed now!